# Two black cords coming from light fixture.

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I am installing a new light fixture but both of the wires coming from it are the same colour. I read that sometimes the neutral wire will have ridges on one side. I’ve attached some pictures, I’m wondering if these are the ridges to denote natural? [image: Here are both wires][image: and here is my suspected ridges]

Comment: The rib appears to be on the side without writing.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct the neutral is alway the identified conductor.